# Having Trouble With Assignments

Tags: python, python-3.4

Using Python 3.4, All lines that include eg.

```
Num = Num + 1
```

Fail to process correctly, It returns an error that goes along the lines of "Article referenced before assignment".

What is the error?

Comment: That sort of thing might happen if you don't have any lines that set e.g. `num = 0` or some initial value. Could you post an example of code where you've run into this problem, so people can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to initialize the variable as follows:

```
Num = 0
...
Num = Num + 1
```